# How to automatically run tests?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, junit

Which properties will be added to run tests automaticlly in JUNIT5?
How do I configure this?

Answer (score 3):

You should use the [maven-surefire-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/), for example:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <argLine>-Xmx1024M ${additional.test.jvm.args}</argLine>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*ManagedTest.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
                <runOrder>alphabetical</runOrder>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Then if you run `mvn test` your code will be both compiled and the tests will be run.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a maven plugin for it:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*Test.java</include>
        </includes>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>**/integration/*ITTest.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

for more information see [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/).